# Showing twelve action buttons without occupying too much space

Tags: color, fonts, mobile, android, button

I want to show user twelve options/buttons such that those options doesn't occupy too much space on screen.I don't want to show icon with each option as it will occupy more space.

The buttons contain various actions for Video Editing like cut,compress,reverse video etc.Above these options/buttons is a video player in which video is playing.

Below are the few designs which I made.Which design looks better from User Experience point of view?Any comments or suggestion are welcome!

Option 1-

[image]

Option 2-

[image]

Option 3-

[image]

Option 4-

[image]

Comment: *If* you want to make the interface more user friendly using colors you might try to gather the actions in some groups that can have slightly different colors. Using 12 different colors seems a bit too busy.

Comment: It's very challenging to give an aesthetic opinion or recommendation without seeing the *entire* aesthetic... i.e. need to see the whole UI, not just buttons.

Comment: @Wolff All these twelve options are for video editing.So they belong to same category.So I think I should use same colour for all those options?

Comment: I mean there must be some way to group those 12 options even though they are all about video editing. You mention "cut", "compress", "reverse". Those are not exactly equal. My *guess* is that you'll use "cut" all the time, "reverse" is more of a special effect and "compress" is for finalizing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which one do *you* prefer ?

You are slated with an issue of integrating form and function (aren't we all).

From a purely aesthetic viewpoint, I prefer # 3 or # 4. I find # 1 and # 2 to be very distracting with all the different colors- especially the lime green button on # 1- it does not seem to go with that more pastel color palette. The highly contrasting colors of #2 I do not like at all.

Perhaps you need the different colored buttons to differentiate the various functions easily for the user? It is really very subjective. Without seeing your entire project layout it is impossible to give any kind of definitive answer to your question. And even with the entire project knowledge, each answer will be unique to each person answering.

So I return to my original question- Which one do you prefer ? You have the information you need to weigh form and function. I say make your choice and go with it.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can categorise the actions? that might make it easier to find the action they want to take.

also, you might want to look at Snapseed, Google's photo editing app, as an inspiration for how they managed to put so many buttons in one screen.